# Reshape/pivot a datafile of key-value pairs with recurring key values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I found many similarly titled questions, but could not find the exact one I am looking for.

I have a datafile like this:

```
title1:A1
title2:A2
title3:A3
title4:A4
title5:A5

title1:B1
title2:B2
title3:B3
title4:B4
title5:B5

title1:C1
title2:C2
title3:C3
title4:C4
title5:C5

title1:D1
title2:D2
title3:D3
title4:D4
title5:D5
```

Using pandas I would like to get a table like this:

```
    title1  title2  title3  title4  title5
0   A1  A2  A3  A4  A5
1   B1  B2  B3  B4  B5
2   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
3   D1  D2  D3  D4  D5
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('colon_sep.txt',header=None,sep=':')
df.columns = ['title','id']

# for loop method
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for t in df.title.unique():
    df2[t] = df[df.title == t]['id'].values
df2
# HOW TO GET THIS BY Advanced methods?
```

I was able to get the required table using for loop.

Is there a better way using groupby or any other advanced method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify your code a bit, to include a `pivot` call at the end for efficiency:

```
df = pd.read_csv('colon_sep.txt', sep=':', header=None)
df.insert(2, 2, df.groupby(0).cumcount())  
df = df.pivot(index=2, columns=0, values=1)
```

```
print(df)

0 title1 title2 title3 title4 title5
2                                   
0     A1     A2     A3     A4     A5
1     B1     B2     B3     B4     B5
2     C1     C2     C3     C4     C5
3     D1     D2     D3     D4     D5
```

Comment: I could not get df['title1']  gives KEY ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

After you do

```
df = pd.read_csv('colon_sep.txt',header=None,sep=':')
```

You can do

```
df= pd.DataFrame({name:list(column[0]) for name,column in dfc.groupby(dfc.index)})
```

Or, if you have the data in a string called `text`, you can do

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[line.split(':')[1] for line in lines.split('\n')] for lines in text.split('\n\n')])`
```

You can get the column names with

```
df.columns = [line.split(':')[0] for line in text.split('\n\n')[0].split('\n')]
```